# Geomesa: DynamoDB as a datastore

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, geomesa

I heard Geowave has launched DynamoDB support. Is Geomesa also planning to support DynamoDB as one of their databases? Is the release planned?

Saw an email in 2016. What is the state for it now?
https://dev.locationtech.org/mhonarc/lists/geomesa-users/msg01894.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of July 2019, GeoMesa doesn't have support for AWS's DynamoDB.  Discussing it on the user and/or dev lists would be the best way to see if there's community interest in that.